# PHP Check for special numbers

Tags: php

I have a simple function which checks if a value is a number and if that number is less than 0.

```
function check_number($value){

    if(!is_numeric(strval($value))){
        return "value must be whole or decimal";
    } else {
        if($value < 0){
            return "value must be bigger than 0";
        }
    }

    return "successful value";
}
```

This functions works all well and good, until special numbers are passed in such as:

- 0xf4c3b00c
- 1e7

These values will still make the function return **"successful value"**.

How can I make these special numbers not return a false positive in my case.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `ctype_digit` will help you to get your required output. `ctype_digit` returns TRUE if every character in the string text is a decimal digit, FALSE otherwise.

Comment: If I use ctype_digit, and pass in "5.5" it returns "value must be whole or decimal"

Comment: How about implementing PHPs filters (FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) instead of writing your own function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php, http://www.devshed.com/c/a/php/validating-boolean-values-and-float-numbers-with-filters-in-php-5/

Comment: `var_dump(filter_var("4.1e7", FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT));` outputs `float(41000000)`

Comment: Can you please consider why you want to force people who enter "1e7" to enter "10000000" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function check_number($value){

    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        return "That is not a number";
    }
    if ($value < 0) {
        return "value must be bigger than 0";
    }
    if(!ctype_digit(str_replace('.', '', $value))){
        return "value must be whole or decimal";
    }

    return "successful value";
}
```

[**SEE DEMO**](https://eval.in/159361)

Comment: That makes sense - I was going to go down the RegExp route, too much Perl man ... though not Ron Perlman ... wait, what ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that would accept 8.9.9 as a number. My method checks for multiple dots first.

Comment: nearly working, `check_number(1e7)` (without quotes) returns successful

Comment: And -8.9 will fail at the first check, so would return "value must be whole or decimal" rather than "value must be bigger than 0".

Comment: @user3597010 If you pass `1e7` to a function without quotes, then it is passed as a number, and will therefore have a value of 10000000. The function has no idea that a shorthand was originally used unless you pass it in as a string.

Comment: I am going to pass `1e7` as a string, (that is a must), so now that makes my only problem being that `.21..3.54...6` is still outputting "successful"

Comment: @user3597010 Alright, I think I got all the kinks worked out, with a lot of help from paul gregory. See update

Comment: +1 @PaulGregory for his conceptual answer and for his help in pointing out bugs here

Comment: input "-1.6.6" or "-3.5fff" and they output "must be bigger than 0", where I would expect the output to me "whole or decimal"

Comment: @user3597010 Yikes, Ok. I think we really did get it this time. See recent update and demo.

Comment: Given that some inputs may have multiple failure reasons, it may be worth restructuring so that a list of errors is built up, rather than simply returning at the first failure found. However, that may be left as an exercise for the OP. (Thanks for the +1s Mark btw)

Comment: @MarkM Brilliant, your help has been second to none. Works like a charm!

Comment: @PaulGregory this is being used in a validate class an I add the error to an array like so `$this->addError("{$item_name} must be a whole or decimal number");`

Answer (score 1):

You have peculiar requirements. Your definition of a number differs from PHP's - 4.1e7 is a number, just not one formatted in a way you like. So you need to look at the number as it appears - as a string.

Check if value is less than 0 first, because later we won't distinguish between a minus sign and any other character.

Count dots in the number string.

If more than 1 dot, return fail.

If just 1 dot, str_replace it out and continue.

Finally, use ctype_digit on the remaining string.

Comment: Looks like an answer without code just gets ignored, even if it catches all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(!is_numeric(strval($value))){
```

into

```
$value = trim($value, "0"); // get value as string and remove leading and trailing zeroes
$value_float = ltrim(floatval($value), "0"); // get float value as string and remove leading zero
if($value !== $value_float){
```

or to make it compacter

```
if(trim($value, "0") !== ltrim(floatval($value), "0")){
```

to check whether the numerical representation is still the same after stringifying.

Comment: input value "1e7" still returns success

Comment: @user3597010 And edited again. Because `!=` should have been `!==`